# How to Upload a File Using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I'm having a problem uploading a file ( the file is called "kickstarter1.csv" it is in the image that I attached) using Pandas in python. In the bottom of the picture I attached, it is saying that the file does not exist.  I found out a way to view the full path of my file which is located at the bottom of the finder window ( it is in the image I attached). How do I code the full path into my pandas code? I'm using Anaconda Navigator ( I'm not sure if that is relevant).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

provide the complete path of your CSV file while reading it through pandas as

`name_you_want = pd.read_csv('path/file_name.csv')`

or go to the specific folder using cd command on notebook and then read the CSV file.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("MacintoshHD/Users/shiffraw/Downloads/kickstarter1.csv")  something like this?